# Code builder not working in Code Town

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

My school decided to purchase *Minecraft Education Edition*, so I tried a couple of Hours of Code to use them for a lesson.
The first one went well, but I had some problems with Code Town map.

I was trying to solve the one asking to collect every glass piece on the ground, I "built" a good solution but the game refused to accept it as good, even if I collected all of them in one go. This means no "Well done!" message and the door remained closed. I even tried with the suggested solution, nothing changed.

I noticed that a strange red message popped up in chat, something like:

> Syntax error: Unexpected value at coreboard "xxx>>yyy<<zzz"

with some meaningless random words at the end.

(I was playing my native language, not English, so I don't know the actual error message.)

What's wrong with the Code builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, there's something wrong with the Italian version.

Since I couldn't find my error I switched to English language from the menu in order to reproduce the same error...
And I got no error message, because **it worked**.

I think that some command was badly translated, and the compiler misinterpreted it giving that syntax error.

**TLDR;**
Switching to English language solved every syntax problem, and the solution was accepted as expected.